# Gulp - doing multiple builds

Tags: coffeescript, gulp

Just starting out with Gulp.

I have more than 20 HTML pages, each page has its own JS files that need to be built via Gulp.

I have something like the following

```
gulp.task('compile-coffee', function () {
    // page1    
    gulp.src('./home/coffee/*.coffee')
        .pipe(coffee())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./home/js'));

    // page2
    gulp.src('./people/coffee/*.coffee')
        .pipe(coffee())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./people/js'));
    });
})
```

Now, if I make changes to any of the files in /people/coffee/*.coffee files, it looks like coffee files from both page1 and page2 are compiled. If I add all 20 pages and more, it obviously feels like a redundant step.

What is a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [gulp-changed](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-changed) plugin like this:

```
gulp.task('compile-coffee', function () {
  // page1    
  gulp.src('./home/coffee/*.coffee')
    .pipe(changed('./home/js', { extension: '.js'}))
    .pipe(coffee())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./home/js'));

  // page2
  gulp.src('./people/coffee/*.coffee')
    .pipe(changed('./people/js', { extension: '.js'}))
    .pipe(coffee())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./people/js'));
  });
})
```

Notice that the extension option should be provided, otherwise it won't work.